# Is there a way to check if a dictionary has a key, and if that key's value is not None in one pass?

Tags: python, dictionary

```
sampleDict = {'1':None}
```

To check if a key exist, and if it's not None, I have to do this

```
if '1' in sampleDict:
    if sampleDict['1'] is not None:
        #do something
```

Is there a more pythonic way to do this in a single pass?

Comment: How about `if sampleDict.get("1") is not None`?

Comment: `if '1' in sampledict and sampledict['1'] is not None`?

Comment: And everyone telling you to use `.get()` has misread your question.

Comment: @larsks i suppose, that also does "two passes", but I'm not sure if the OP really is just trying to use less lines/indentation or if they really care about retrieving the value from the dict twice

Comment: I don't think it is wrong to use `get`. Doubtlessly that `get` cannot confirm that `key` is in or not in the `sampleDict`. But as this is chained if condition, only if we have `"1"` in the dict and it is not `None`, then we can `do something`. Which can be ensured by `sampleDict.get("1") is not None`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code:

```
if '1' in sampleDict:
    if sampleDict['1'] is not None:
        #do something
```

Can be simplified to:

```
if sampleDict.get('1') is not None:
    #do something
```

It subsumes the first if-clause by the fact that `dict.get()` returns `None` if not found.  It subsumes the second if-clause by the fact that `dict.get()` returns the same value as `[]` if the key is found.

Comment: The question isn't asking about the value, its asking about the key....

Comment: @Z4-tier, Surely from OP's code, he is checking if the value of key is not `None`..

Comment: @Austin The code is an example though. The question title applies much more broadly than just this code sample.

Comment: If you need to use the non-None value in the "do something" block, this would be a great opportunity to use the new `:=` "walrus" inline assignment operator in Python 3.8 (that came out a month ago). `if (value := sampleDict.get('1')) is not None: do_something(value)`

Comment: @Z4-tier: Oh, apparently I'm confused about my release timings, you're right. I've edited.

Answer (score 0):

If I take the question to mean exactly what it says ("check if a key exist, and if it's not None"), then you want `dict.keys()`.

You must check if the key is `not None`:

```
if key is not None:
  do_something()
```

and that it exists:

```
if key is not None and key in my_dict.keys(): 
  do_something()
```

Comment: The question states "check if a key exist, and if it's not None"

Comment: This answers the question in the title, but checking the if the key itself is `None` is not what the questioner's code does. I suspect the title is misleading.

Comment: I upvoted since I think your answer is more correct as far as the question in title is concerned and also since OP specifically asked for a more 'pythonic' way. As such, explicitly using ```keys``` is better in my opinion.

Comment: @pavel, There is no need to explicitly use `keys`. You can just do `key in my_dict`.

Comment: @Austin, I know that the default behaviour of a dictionary is to search in keys, but explicit declaration makes the code easier to read. And since the original question included the part about a 'more pythonic' way - then explicitly using ```keys()``` is just that .